# how to define multiple classes' hover event in css?

Tags: html, css

In css how can I define multiple class' hover events to use the same properties.
This doesn't seem to work:

```
.my_div:hover .my_td:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The answers got it. Also note that a space implies that the second element is a child of the first; so you are actually applying a CSS rule here to <td class="my_td">'s that only occur within <div class="my_div">

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You should separate with a comma, like this:

```
.my_div:hover, .my_td:hover {
      border: 1px solid red;
}
.contact-dpd:hover .contact-content, .work-dpd:hover .work-content{
     display:block
}
```

Comment: @omega When an answer resolves your issue, click the green tick next to it to mark it as "accepted."

Comment: can we have only one :hover for both TD and DIV?

Comment: Strangel!!. 4 correct and similar answers, answered on the same day, same time! Luckily the mouse has "hovered" to your answer and marked it as "accepted" : )  +1

Answer (score 11):

Add a comma in between: `.my_div:hover, .my_td:hover`.

Answer (score 9):

This should work

```
.my_div:hover, .my_td:hover {
        border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

try

```
.my_div:hover, .my_td:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Take look at CSS Selectors Level 4:

> The `:where()` CSS pseudo-class function takes a selector list as its argument, and selects any element that can be selected by one of the selectors in that list.
>
> The difference between `:where()` and `:is()` is that `:where()` always has 0 specificity, whereas `:is()` takes on the specificity of the most specific selector in its arguments.

```css
:where(.a, .b):hover {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
```

It also works with selecting child elements:

```css
:where(header, footer) p:hover {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

:where(main, aside) p:hover {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

:where(header, footer) a {
  color: red;
}

b, i {
  color: green;
}

main :where(b, i) {
  outline: 1px solid;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>header <a href="#">link</a></p>
</header>
<main>
  <p>main <a href="#">link</a> <b>bold</b> <i>italic</i></p>
</main>
<aside>
  <p>aside <a href="#">link</a> <b>bold</b> <i>italic</i></p>
</aside>
<footer>
  <p>footer <a href="#">link</a></p>
</footer>
```

Comment: i know this isn't the specific answer that the OP was looking for, but this is how you SHOULD right it to DRY up code. Upvote.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what `where` does that a simple comma doesn't do.

Answer (score -3):

You should separate CSS classes and events this way :

```
.my_div, .my_td {
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid CSS

Comment: Specifically it's Sass