# Can you set multiple elements hover declaration to only one div?

Tags: css

I have few elements with the same property once its hovered over. I would like to know if I can set all those element at once such as below

```
 #el1:hover el2:hover el3:hover .test{
  }
```

I know the normal way would be

```
  #el1:hover .test{
  }
```

Is it possible to do something like this or similar on css, Please few free to update the question title as I found it hard to describe the problem.

Comment: Yes it will be work, you just need to add comma after each class aur id `#el1:hover, #el2:hover, #el3:hover, .test{ }`

Comment: `#el1:hover .test, #el2:hover .test,  #el3:hover .test { ... }`

Comment: I think you must read the rules in this page: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do commas and spaces in multiple classes mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344284/what-do-commas-and-spaces-in-multiple-classes-mean-in-css)

Comment: not clear: .test element is inside both #el1, #el2 and #el3? Could you share the markup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132884/how-to-define-multiple-classes-hover-event-in-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `id` of the parent elements starts with `el` you can use the [`[attr^="value"]` starts-with attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```
[id^="el"]:hover .test{
  // some code
}
```

---

Otherwise you will have to use the `,` to separate the selectors

```
#el1:hover .test,
#el2:hover .test,
#el3:hover .test{
 // some code
}
```

---

Finally you could add a common class to the parent elements so that you can target it directly

```
<div id="el1" class="common-class">
  <span class="test">..</span>
</div>

<div id="el5" class="common-class">
  <span class="test">..</span>
</div>
```

and use

```
.common-class:hover .test{
  // some code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
#el1:hover, #el2:hover, #el3:hover .test{
  // some code
}
```

To have a deeper understanding of CSS Selectors read

- [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
- [Combinators and groups of selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be work, you just need to add comma after each class or id. That comma will seperate the css class or id and style will be apply on all mentioned classes, ids or element references.

```
#el1:hover, #el2:hover, #el3:hover .test{ 
  some style
}
```

**CSS Group Selector**

When you apply same css style properties on diffrent elements using Classes, ID, or references is called group selector.

For example if you want to make color of following elements

```
<h2>Group Selector Heading</h2>
<p>Group Selector Paragraph</p>
<div class="container">Group Selector Container</div>
<span  id="message">Group Selector Message</span>
```

You can apply color on all above elements by using group selector method. It will minimize the code.

```
h2, p, .container, #message{
    color:#FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#el1:hover, #el2:hover, #el3:hover , .test{ 
 color:orange
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="el1">My First CSS Example</h1>
<h1 id="el2">My First CSS Example</h1>
<h1 id="el3">My First CSS Example</h1>
<h1 class="test">My First CSS Example</h1>

</body>
</html>
```